# How can delete all the spaces and sends in prolog file?

Tags: file, prolog

I want to read a file and delete all the spaces and sends (nl) these and put everything in a list.

For example:
From

```
myfile.txt = (First Line (Second ( line ) and Third and other)
To List = [FirstLine(Second(line)andthirdandother)]
```

How it can be achieved?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your Prolog has the appropriate builtins, like [read_file_to_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_file_to_codes/3)/3, and [code_type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=code_type/2)/2, you can do in this way

```
file_to_list(File, List) :-
  read_file_to_codes(File, Codes, []),
  exclude(bad_char, Codes, List).

bad_char(C) :-
  code_type(C, space).
```

Comment: read_file(File, List):-
open(File, read, S),
set_input(S),
read_file_to_codes(File, Codes, List),
close(S).


read_file_to_codes(File, Codes, []),
  exclude(bad_char, Codes, List),


bad_char(C) :- 
 code_type(C, space).

Comment: does not work, I can not implement it with the reading of the file,

Comment: read_file('prova.txt',L).
          (1)    call:read_file('prova.txt',_1055) ? 
          (2)    call:at_end_of_stream('prova.txt') ? 
     ERROR at  clause 1 of prolog:at_end_of_stream/1 !!
     EXISTENCE ERROR- past_eof/1: prova.txt not an open stream
          (2)    exception:at_end_of_stream('prova.txt') ? 
          (1)    redo:read_file('prova.txt',_1055) ? 
          (3)    call:at_end_of_stream('prova.txt') ? 
     ERROR at  clause 1 of prolog:at_end_of_stream/1 !!
     EXISTENCE ERROR- past_eof/1: prova.txt not an open stream

Comment: (3)    exception:at_end_of_stream('prova.txt') ? 
     ERROR at  clause 1 of prolog:read/2 !!
     EXISTENCE ERROR- read/3: prova.txt not an open stream
          (1)    exception:read_file('prova.txt',_1055) ? 
no

Comment: you should try ?- file_to_list('c:/prova.txt', L).

Comment: I am on ubuntu and the file prova.txt is in the same folder of the main file file_list.pl

Comment: then try `?- trace,file_to_list('prova.txt',L).` and post the output.